# Why spatial transformer network (STN) is not working on image

Tags: matrix, numbers

I am trying to subject a one image array to STN using code from https://github.com/kevinzakka/spatial-transformer-network :

```
def STNfn(x): 
    import tensorflow as tf
    print(x.shape)
    B,W,H,C = x.shape
    # identity transform
    initial = np.array([[1., 0, 0], [0, 1., 0]])
    initial = initial.astype('float32').flatten()
    # localization network  
    n_fc = 6
    W_fc1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([H*W*C, n_fc]), name='W_fc1')
    b_fc1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial, name='b_fc1')
    h_fc1 = tf.matmul(tf.zeros([B, H*W*C]), W_fc1) + b_fc1 

    # spatial transformer layer
    from stn import spatial_transformer_network as transformer
    h_trans = transformer(x, h_fc1) 
    return h_trans

fname = 'testimage.jpg'
img = plt.imread(fname)
img = STNfn(np.array([img]))
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type uint8 
that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
```

I have tried to replace float32 with `np.uint8`, but it does not help.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

n_fc = 6 has to be a float32 maybe? Not familar with Python, in Java it is like 6.0f for float and just 6 is integer.